# No Way to Format Cell as Month-Date-Year in PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel

I've am trying to format cells in an Excel document I create with PHPExcel using the setFormatCode method.  I've been going through the list of 'FORMAT_DATE_xxxxxxx' options associated with this method, but I've been unable to find one that lists the month, date, and year in that order.  Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 2):

You missed FORMAT_DATE_XLSX14 and FORMAT_DATE_XLSX22

You also missed the fact that these are simply predefined string values, and that you can use any valid Excel numberformat string value that you set yourself.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C9')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
        'mm-dd-yyyy'  // my own personal preferred format that isn't predefined
    );
```

Comment: And these are defined in PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php if you want to have more clear examples. If you have your own preferred format then I recommend creating your own defines instead of extending this list.